# Find distance between inside corner of polygon and perimeter of circle

Tags: javascript, math, trigonometry

I am trying to calculate the length of the red line in the examples in the image. The information I have is:

- Coordinates of all points of the polygon
- Radius of the circle
- Angle of each corner

I want to place a circle with a given radius as close to a corner of the polygon as possible, meaning the outer tangents between the circle and the corner coordinate is where the circle will rest against the edges - like in the image supplied.

I don't know how to calculate that little extra space in addition to the circle's radius in order to keep the circle from intersecting the edges.

[image]

Comment: You forgot to include your attempt to solve this problem.

Comment: Once the math part is worked out, the JavaScript part should be pretty obvious. The math part is not really a programming thing however, it's math.

Comment: @DarrylNoakes seems to me the basic problem is a circle of a certain radius squeezed into a particular angle. The rest of the polygon is just a constraint on the radius.

Comment: One core approach is to find two parallel lines, one for each of the lines making the vertex, and radius distance away from said lines. The coords for the circle is their intersection point.

Comment: I believe I didn't read carefully enough and misunderstood. You only want to calculate the length of the red line, not the actual position of the circle? If you are calculating the position in the end, how are you doing it from just that length?

Answer (score 1):

Image below shows what I did to figure it out.
I realized there will always be a right triangle forming between the vertex, the circle's centre, and the point where the circle touches a side of the polygon.

I know the angle where the circle is approaching, and I know the radius of the circle, so I have both a side length and an angle to work from.

The distance to the circle centre from the vertex can be figured out using the law of cosines.

[image]

Comment: Yes, that's because the edge has to be tangent to the circle, and a tangent line is always perpendicular to the radius.

Answer (score 0):

Okay here's what you do:

1. Find the angle formed at the corner that the circle is approaching. You can do this using arctan(arctan2) on the specific line segments in your polygon. Subtract angle 2 from angle 1 and divide by 2 you have the approach angle.
2. Now do tan(approach angle - smaller angle) which will give you the slope.
3. The distance along the approach angle will be radius / slope.

This *should* work